# (Regular Expressions) 2Liner→1Liner

Tags: regex, dxf

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad english!

I want

'Odd rows' 'CRLF' 'Even rows' CRLF' → 'Odd rows' ',' 'Even rows' 'CRLF'

Example Input:

```
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
```

Desired Output:

```
  0,SECTION
  2,HEADER
```

What I have tried:

```
Find: (.*)\n(.*)\n
Replace: $1,$2\n
```

I want ー　Easy to see dxf

Comment: I want - you to do your own homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example data you could capture one or more digits in capturing group 1 followed by matching a newline.

In the replacement use group 1 followed by a comma.

**Match**

`(\d+)(?:r?\n|\r)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DwUEpE/1)

**Replace**

`$1,`

Answer (score 2):

`.` matches a newline the same as it matches any other characer, so the first `.*` is going to gobble up the whole string and leave nothing left.

Instead, use a character group that excludes `\n`. Also, it's not clear whether your final line terminates with a `\n` or not, so the Regex should handle for that:

Find

```
([^\n]*)\n([^\n]*)(\n|$)
```

Replace

```
$1,$2$3
```

Breakdown:

- `([^\n]*)` - 0 or more characters that are not `\n`
- `\n`
- `([^\n]*)`
- `(\n|$)` - `\n` or end of string

Answer (score 1):

you should match enter and space also, because there may be multiple spaces and new line available in string 
try this regex-

> "0\nSECTION\n  2\nHEADER".replace(/([\d]+)([\s\n]+)([^\d\s\n]*)/g,"$1,$3")

```js
var myStr = `  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER`;

var output = myStr.replace(/([\d]+)([\s\n]+)([^\d\s\n]*)/g,"$1,$3");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

DXF file ok

ODD line abc...

(AWK)

```
NR%2!=0{L1=$0}
NR%2==0{print L1 "," $0;L1=""}
```